# Convertir VARCHAR a DATE en un SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla en cuyos registro tiene una fecha, pero esta fecha esta guardada como `VARCHAR`, me comentaron que podía convertirlo en `DATE` en el `SELECT`.
Esto es lo que tengo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE CONVERT (date(15), fecha, 103) = '1/01/2017';
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> Msg 291, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 CAST or CONVERT: invalid
>   attributes specified for type 'date'

los registros de la tabla son con este formato en `VARCHAR`

```
16/06/2016
20/06/2016
20/06/2016
16/07/2016
```

Comment: Lo mejor sería no guardar una fecha como `VARCHAR` en primer lugar.

Comment: El problema es que no tengo acceso a modificar esa tabla

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Imaginemos datos como estos:

```
fecha_var
1/01/2017
2/01/2017
3/01/2017
40/01/2017
```

Al final puse un valor incorrecto a propósito: `40/01/2017`.

Mi columna de prueba se llama `fecha_var`.

Esta consulta :

```
SELECT * 
FROM fechas_20171115 
WHERE CONVERT (datetime, fecha_var, 103) = '01/01/2017';
```

Traerá los datos, pero dará el siguiente error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Y escrita así:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT (datetime, fecha_var, 103) 
FROM fechas_20171115;
```

Traerá sólo las tres primeras filas y dará el mismo error de antes.

---

### Soluciones

Un gran problema cuando asignamos tipos de datos que no corresponden (como es el caso aquí al usar un `VARCHAR` cuando debería ser un `DATETIME`), son los errores que se cometen al entrar los datos.

Significa que en la columna pueden haber fechas inválidas. Entonces tienes que contemplar esa posibilidad.

Veamos dos posibles soluciones.

#### Solución 1: SQL-SERVER 2012+

En SQL-Server 2012 y posteriores existe la función [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) la cual:

> Devuelve una conversión de valor al tipo de datos especificado si la
>   conversión se realiza correctamente; de lo contrario, devuelve `NULL`.

La consulta con `TRY_CONVERT` sería:

```
SELECT
    (TRY_CONVERT(date, fecha_var, 103)) as FECHA_DATE
FROM fechas_20171115;
```

#### Solución 2: SQL-Server 2012-

Podrás resolverlo con esta consulta:

```
SET LANGUAGE british;

SELECT
    (CASE WHEN 
        (ISDATE(fecha_var) > 0) 
             THEN CONVERT(DATE, FECHA_VAR) 
             ELSE CONVERT(DATE, '01/01/1900') 
     END) as FECHA_DATE
FROM fechas_20171115;
```

**Resultado:**

```
    FECHA_DATE
    01.01.2017 00:00:00
    01.02.2017 00:00:00
    01.03.2017 00:00:00
    01.01.1900 00:00:00
```

Como podrás ver, la consulta te trae la fecha Epoch (`01.01.1900`)  cuando los valores sean incorrectos.

---

### Curar el problema en la raíz

Aunque dices que no tienes acceso a modificar la base de datos. Si lo tuvieras, el problema se resolvería creando una nueva columna en la tabla, llamada por ejemplo `FECHADATE`, y haciendo un `UPDATE`:

#### SQL-Server 2012+

```
UPDATE  fechas_20171115 
SET FECHA_DATE = (SELECT (TRY_CONVERT(date, fecha_var, 103)) as TMP);
```

#### SQL-Server 2012-

```
SET LANGUAGE british;
UPDATE  fechas_20171115 SET FECHA_DATE =
(    SELECT
        (CASE WHEN 
            (ISDATE(fecha_var) > 0) 
                 THEN CONVERT(DATE, FECHA_VAR) 
                 ELSE CONVERT(DATE, '01/01/1900') 
         END) as TMP
 );


--Probamos ahora lo que ha ocurrido

SELECT * FROM fechas_20171115;

SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = 'fechas_20171115'
ORDER  BY ordinal_position;
```

**Resultado:**

```
id  fecha_var   FECHA_DATE
1   1/01/2017   01.01.2017 00:00:00
2   2/01/2017   01.02.2017 00:00:00
3   3/01/2017   01.03.2017 00:00:00
4   40/01/2017  01.01.1900 00:00:00

column_name    data_type
id             int
fecha_var      varchar
FECHA_DATE     datetime
```

Luego tendrás que hacer una revisión, verificando si hay fechas con Epoch (01-01-1900), indicativo de que el valor de la vieja columna `VARCHAR` no era una fecha válida. Tendrás que corregir de alguna manera, investigando cual era la fecha correcta que debería ir en esa columna. `[broma]Esperemos que no hayan despedido al que digitó esos datos y se acuerde cual era la fecha correcta y que explique por qué estaba dormido ese día y cuántos errores como ese habrá cometido.[/broma]`

Comment: Utilice la solución, pero hay un problema, me marca como fecha Epoch este registro `16/04/2016`, no se si por el formato dd/mm/yyyy que utilizo

Comment: Colocando esto antes del select se solucionan las fechas Epoch `SET LANGUAGE british`

Comment: Sí, porque lo interpreta como día `04` del mes `16`. Entonces puedes usar `TRY_CONVERT`, válido a partir de SQL-Server 2012: **`SELECT
        (TRY_CONVERT(date, fecha_var, 103)) as FECHA_DATE
    FROM fechas_20171115;`**. Si no tendrás que hacer una conversión del varchar, cambiando la posición de los días/meses.

Comment: Ya quedo solucionado, muy completa su respuesta, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Como ya se explicó en la respuesta de @Marcos Pérez, la sintaxis correcta para la conversión es:

```
convert(datetime, fecha, 103)
```

Pero esa misma conversión tienes que aplicarla a la fecha con la que comparas:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE CONVERT(datetime, fecha, 103) = CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/2017', 103)
```

... o, para simplificar un poco, puedes usar el formato `YYYYMMDD` que no requiere una conversión explícita:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE CONVERT(datetime, fecha, 103) = '20170101'
```

Si a pesar de esto cambios sigues recibiendo errores, eso significa que no todos tus datos siguen el formato `DD/MM/YYYY` como mencionas en tu pregunta. Esos son los riesgos de usar un tipo incorrecto para guardar los datos. Te tocará conseguir los registros que tienen un formato incorrecto y corregirlos.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente tendrías que utilizar el tipo de variable datetime en vez de date(15) para que ese convert te funcionase bien.Te adjunto el enlace del post original por si quieres echarle un vistazo , asi como la consulta final.[Post original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780668/how-to-convert-a-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-datetime-in-sql-server)

```
   SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE CONVERT (datetime, fecha, 103) = '01/01/2017';
```

Comment: me da este error al ejecutar:
`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: Te aseguraste de poner todas los caracteres de la fecha ? Porque en tu pregunta , le estabas intentando pasar una fecha incompleta  1/01/2017, cuando deberia ser 01/01/2017

Comment: si, la tengo completa dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: En tu pregunta, no se ve la fecha que le estas pasando al CONVERT, aparte de que yo me refería a la que se le pasa como condicion del where