# De qué manera puedo convertir 2 campos de una tabla a datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

quisiera saber de que manera puedo convertir 2 campos de una tabla a datetime.

Resulta que actualmente estoy realizando una aplicación para una empresa la cual me dio una base de datos, esta tiene los campos fecha y hora pero tiene un tipo de dato erróneo ya que son de tipo varchar, lo que hice fue crear una vista gracias a un compañero de la comunidad que me dio la solución la cual es la siguiente:

```
CREATE VIEW Test AS 
SELECT CAST(Fecha as DATE) 'FechaDate', CAST(Hora AS Time) 'HoraTime'
FROM Tabla
```

Esa solución me ha sido de ayuda, pero para la consulta que se requiere no me sirve que los campos fechas y hora estén separados, me veo en la necesidad de crear un solo campo de tipo date time partiendo de los campos fecha y hora, ya sea convirtiendo la fecha y la hora que están en varchar o creando una vista que junte estos 2 campos y forme uno solo de tipo datetime.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda, no soy experto en el tema y la verdad cualquier idea o sugerencia me seria de mucha ayuda ya que no cuento con mucho tiempo de plazo y no se me ocurren mas ideas

Comment: Ya probaste con CONCAT(tabla.campo,tabla2.campo2) Saludos :)

Comment: Si puedes, resuelve este problema de raíz, normalizando los datos. Una buena estrategia sería crear una nueva columna en la tabla y actualizarla mediante una consulta que concatene las columnas de la fecha y de la hora en un solo valor. Dependiendo de cómo estén introducidos los datos en esas dos columnas tendrás que hacer algunas modificaciones en la consulta, lo esencial es que te produzca una cadena válida para convertir a `DATETIME`. [Revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/117609/29967)  donde se aborda el problema con más detalles y se dan soluciones para v. 2008 y 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Estos son algunos caminos que podrías tomar:

--**Por creacion de vistas - Metodo 1 CAST**

```
CREATE VIEW Test
AS
SELECT
  CAST(Fecha + ' ' + Hora AS datetime) AS Fecha
FROM Tabla
```

--**Por creacion de vistas - Metodo 2 CONVERT**

```
CREATE VIEW Test
AS
SELECT
  CONVERT(datetime, Fecha + ' ' + Hora) AS Fecha
FROM Tabla
```

--**Añadir nueva columna a tu tabla fisica directamente y despues darle el valor a esa columna**

```
ALTER TABLE Tabla ADD Fecha datetime NULL

UPDATE Tabla
SET Fecha = CONVERT(datetime, Fecha + ' ' + Hora)
```