# Ejecutar consulta asignada a variable sp_executesql SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy realizando un procedimiento en el cual necesito ir concatenando en una variable la consulta ya que algun parametro puede venir vacio o pueden haber varias combinaciones de venir dos vacios y uno no, o al contrario, por lo que estoy trabajando de la siguiente manera

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_ConsultarPolizasSinInventario(@pProveedor INT, @pPoliza INT, @pFechaIni VARCHAR(50), @pFechaFin VARCHAR(50))

WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN


DECLARE 
    @sConsulta NVARCHAR(500)

    
    IF @pProveedor <> 0
        SET @sConsulta += N'AND NumProveedor = @pProveedor ' 
    IF @pPoliza <> 0
        SET @sConsulta += 'AND NumPoliza = @pPoliza '
    IF @pFechaIni <> 0
        SET @sConsulta += 'AND FechaElabora >= @pFechaIni AND FechaElabora <= @pFechaFin'  

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        
    SELECT numpoliza,NumFactura,pagoproveedor,fechaelabora, NumProveedor, cancelada FROM HistFacturasdeproveedor
    WHERE TipoPoliza = 'S' EXECUTE sp_executesql @sConsulta
    
END
```

Pero al parecer en el Select que regresa ignora la variable @sConsulta y hace el select solo con la condicion de TipoPoliza = 'S'
que es lo que estoy realizando mal?

Este es el execute que mando al procedimiento una vez creado

`EXEC Proc_ConsultarPolizasSinInventario 16251, 0, '0', '0'`

Deberia traerme los datos de ese proveedor al ser el unico parametro con valor pero no sucede asi

Comment: Esto no lleva una etiqueta de postgresql

Comment: Que es ese Execute en el medio del select?

Comment: @gbianchi https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15 estoy revisando documentacion y así es como entendi se realizaba con un EXECUTE

Comment: Sacaste la base de datos.. entonces para que base de datos es esto?

Comment: no.. nada que ver.. eso que me estas mostrando pasa un query y una definicion de datos.. vos solo estas pasando un pedazo de un where..

Comment: como lo dice @gbianchi en el where solo estas pasando TipoPolisa = 'S' es por eso que tu consulta funciona, pero no como quieres, intenta pasarle tambien tu variable sConsulta con un AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se suelen resolver ese tipo de parámetros con una query dinámica. Lo más normal es realizarlo con un Or.

Por ejemplo:

```
Create table HistFacturasdeproveedor 
(   
    numPoliza int,
    numFactura int,
    numProveedor int,
    pagoProveedor int,
    FechaIni varchar(50),
    fechaFin varchar(50),
    FechaElabora varchar(50),
    cancelada varchar(10),
    TipoPoliza varchar(1)
);

GO
INSERT INTO HistFacturasdeproveedor (
numPoliza, numFactura, numProveedor, pagoProveedor,
 FechaIni, fechaFin,FechaElabora, cancelada, TipoPoliza)
values
(1,1,16251,3,'2020/01/01','2020/02/01','2020/02/01','c','S'),
(1,2,16251,4,'2020/01/01','2020/02/01','2020/02/01','c','S'),
(2,3,16300,7,'2020/01/01','2020/02/01','2020/02/01','c','S'),
(2,4,16400,8,'2020/01/01','2020/02/01','2020/02/01','c','S');
go
```

Nota: Es posible que las columnas no sean exactamente las tuyas, ni siquiera del mismo tipo, porque utilizar fechas como varchar y según tú código evaluar si son mayores o no, puede ser al menos extraño.  Aunque para el ejemplo es válido.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_ConsultarPolizasSinInventario(
@pProveedor INT, @pPoliza INT, @pFechaIni VARCHAR(50), @pFechaFin VARCHAR(50))

WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    SELECT numpoliza,NumFactura,numProveedor,fechaelabora, NumProveedor, cancelada
            FROM HistFacturasdeproveedor
                    WHERE TipoPoliza = 'S'
                    AND (numProveedor = @pProveedor or @pProveedor = 0)
                    AND (numPoliza = @pPoliza OR @pPoliza = 0)
                    AND (
                        (FechaElabora >= @pFechaIni OR @pFechaIni = '0') 
                        AND 
                        (FechaElabora <= @pFechaFin OR @pFechaFin = '0')
                        );
                    

    
END
go
```

Si observas el procedure, directamente aplicamos en las restricciones where, donde la columna de la tabla sea = al parámetro OR el parámetro sea el valor especificado como no filtrar.

```
EXEC Proc_ConsultarPolizasSinInventario 16251, 0, '0', '0'
```

[image: Resultado]

Otra opción es utilizar parámetros por defecto.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_ConsultarPolizasSinInventario
(@pProveedor INT, @pPoliza INT=NULL, @pFechaIni VARCHAR(50)=NULL, @pFechaFin VARCHAR(50)= NULL)

WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    SELECT numpoliza,NumFactura,numProveedor,fechaelabora, NumProveedor, cancelada
            FROM HistFacturasdeproveedor
                    WHERE TipoPoliza = 'S'
                    AND (numProveedor = @pProveedor or @pProveedor = 0)
                    AND (numPoliza = @pPoliza OR @pPoliza IS NULL)
                    AND (
                        (FechaElabora >= @pFechaIni OR @pFechaIni IS NULL) 
                        AND 
                        (FechaElabora <= @pFechaFin OR @pFechaFin IS NULL)
                        );
END
```

Esto sería lo mismo, pero la invocación sería tal que:

```
EXEC Proc_ConsultarPolizasSinInventario 16251, 1
--o
EXEC Proc_ConsultarPolizasSinInventario @pProveedor = 16251, @pPoliza = 1;
```

Y según necesitas añades parámetros. También pueden ser nominales.

También se puede realizar con un exec sp_executeSQL pero entonces tienes que montar toda la query dinámica. Si no tienes problemas de rendimiento, este método es mucho mejor, y más fácil de implementar.

Comment: Gracias, ya pude resolverlo, pero como duda tengo, por qué es raro o mal comparar fechas recibidas como varchar? ya resolví mi problema pero quisiera saber por que está mal para evitarme malas practicas en el futuro

Comment: Para trabajar con fechas, SQL Server tiene los tipos de datos, date, datetime, datetime2, etc. Porque son más rápidos y precisos. Disponen de muchas funciones para ellos. Tienen una dependencia menor del formato que establezca el cliente. Son menos susceptibles a errores de codificación. No puedes grabar días inexistentes. Tal que el 30 de febrero. Como no has puesto ejemplos de la codificación utilizada, tampoco te puedo precisar los posibles errores. [fechas varchar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117586/convertir-varchar-a-date-en-un-select)