# Error al convertir de varchar a datetime SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Estoy usando SQL Server 2008 R2, estoy haciendo una consulta de selección `SELECT` que es la siguiente:

```
SELECT SalesOrderID
    , ShipDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN '7/28/2011 00:00:00' AND '7/29/2011 23:59:59'
```

Me da el siguiente error

> Comenzó a ejecutar la consulta en la línea 125 Msg 242, Level 16,
> State 3, Line 1 La conversión del tipo de datos varchar en datetime
> produjo un valor fuera de intervalo. Tiempo total de ejecución:
> 00:00:00.011

Para solucionarlo hice lo siguiente:

```
SELECT SalesOrderID
        , ShipDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, '7/28/2011 00:00:00', 22) 
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, '7/29/2011 23:59:59', 22)
```

Select a la tabla

```
   SalesOrderID,RevisionNumber,OrderDate,DueDate,ShipDate,Status,OnlineOrderFlag,SalesOrderNumber,PurchaseOrderNumber,AccountNumber,CustomerID,SalesPersonID,TerritoryID,BillToAddressID,ShipToAddressID,ShipMethodID,CreditCardID,CreditCardApprovalCode,CurrencyRateID,SubTotal,TaxAmt,Freight,TotalDue,Comment,rowguid,ModifiedDate
43659,8,2011-05-31 00:00:00.000,2011-06-12 00:00:00.000,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000,5,0,SO43659,PO522145787,10-4020-000676,29825,279,5,985,985,5,16281,105041Vi84182,NULL,20565.6206,1971.5149,616.0984,23153.2339,NULL,79b65321-39ca-4115-9cba-8fe0903e12e6,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000
43660,8,2011-05-31 00:00:00.000,2011-06-12 00:00:00.000,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000,5,0,SO43660,PO18850127500,10-4020-000117,29672,279,5,921,921,5,5618,115213Vi29411,NULL,1294.2529,124.2483,38.8276,1457.3288,NULL,738dc42d-d03b-48a1-9822-f95a67ea7389,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000
43661,8,2011-05-31 00:00:00.000,2011-06-12 00:00:00.000,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000,5,0,SO43661,PO18473189620,10-4020-000442,29734,282,6,517,517,5,1346,85274Vi6854,4,32726.4786,3153.7696,985.5530,36865.8012,NULL,d91b9131-18a4-4a11-bc3a-90b6f53e9d74,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000
43662,8,2011-05-31 00:00:00.000,2011-06-12 00:00:00.000,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000,5,0,SO43662,PO18444174044,10-4020-000227,29994,282,6,482,482,5,10456,125295Vi53935,4,28832.5289,2775.1646,867.2389,32474.9324,NULL,4a1ecfc0-cc3a-4740-b028-1c50bb48711c,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000
43663,8,2011-05-31 00:00:00.000,2011-06-12 00:00:00.000,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000,5,0,SO43663,PO18009186470,10-4020-000510,29565,276,4,1073,1073,5,4322,45303Vi22691,NULL,419.4589,40.2681,12.5838,472.3108,NULL,9b1e7a40-6ae0-4ad3-811c-a64951857c4b,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000
43664,8,2011-05-31 00:00:00.000,2011-06-12 00:00:00.000,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000,5,0,SO43664,PO16617121983,10-4020-000397,29898,280,1,876,876,5,806,95555Vi4081,NULL,24432.6088,2344.9921,732.8100,27510.4109,NULL,22a8a5da-8c22-42ad-9241-839489b6ef0d,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000
43665,8,2011-05-31 00:00:00.000,2011-06-12 00:00:00.000,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000,5,0,SO43665,PO16588191572,10-4020-000146,29580,283,1,849,849,5,15232,35568Vi78804,NULL,14352.7713,1375.9427,429.9821,16158.6961,NULL,5602c304-853c-43d7-9e79-76e320d476cf,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000
43666,8,2011-05-31 00:00:00.000,2011-06-12 00:00:00.000,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000,5,0,SO43666,PO16008173883,10-4020-000511,30052,276,4,1074,1074,5,13349,105623Vi69217,NULL,5056.4896,486.3747,151.9921,5694.8564,NULL,e2a90057-1366-4487-8a7e-8085845ff770,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000
43667,8,2011-05-31 00:00:00.000,2011-06-12 00:00:00.000,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000,5,0,SO43667,PO15428132599,10-4020-000646,29974,277,3,629,629,5,10370,55680Vi53503,NULL,6107.0820,586.1203,183.1626,6876.3649,NULL,86d5237d-432d-4b21-8abc-671942f5789d,2011-06-07 00:00:00.000
```

Pero sigue saliendo el mismo error, ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: ¿qué tipo de dato es `ShipDate`?

Comment: Intenta cambiar las barras inclinadas por guiones y nos cuentas: `'7-28-2011 00:00:00'`

Comment: Te invito a leer la respuesta a un problema parecido:https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117586/convertir-varchar-a-date-en-un-select?rq=1

Comment: @jachguate DateTime

Comment: @Arriel Sale el mismo error `SELECT SalesOrderID
    , ShipDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN '7-28-2011 00:00:00' AND '7-29-2011 23:59:59'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera `yyyymmdd`

```
    SELECT SalesOrderID
    , ShipDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE ShipDate BETWEEN '20110728 00:00:00' AND '20110729 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente esta solución!